# Python Flask - Need to insert timestamp when a csv file is uploaded and posted to database

Tags: python, file, flask, timestamp

I'm creating a form that allows you to upload a .csv file and then on submit, adds the uploaded file to the database in a table called "Files".

What i'm trying to figure out is how to insert a timestamp for when the file is uploaded, so that on the HTML side, it shows the uploaded file, along with the date and time it was uploaded/posted.

What I tried before was giving me the local time, and it would keep changing with refresh, but I want the exact date and time the file is uploaded. In essence, something like the "Created" timestamp when you click on a file's properties in File Explorer.

I realize I may need to add another attribute for DateTime in my Files class/table so that it can be posted to the database, and then rendered onto the HTML.

Here is my class "Files":

```
class Files(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    f_source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('funding_source.id'), nullable=True)
```

Here is where i'm posting the uploaded file to the database:

```
@main.route("/upload_file", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csvfile' in request.files:
        f = request.files['csvfile']

        # pressing submit without uploading a file
        if f.filename == "":
            flash("No selected file. Please attach CSV file", "danger")
            return redirect(url_for('main.alloc_summ'))
        # only allowing .csv extension files
        if f.filename and not allowed_file(f.filename):
            flash("Only CSV Files Allowed", "danger")
            return redirect(url_for('main.alloc_summ'))
        # opening file, reading it in, and inserting values to database
        if f.filename != '' and allowed_file(f.filename):
            with open('<hidden path url>', 'r') as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                new_file = Files(name=f.filename, data=f.read())
                db.session.add(new_file)
                db.session.commit()
                flash("File Uploaded", "success")
                return redirect(url_for('main.alloc_summ'))
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could guide me on how to get the timestamp for when a file is uploaded/posted to the database so that I can query the Files table to show the file and timestamp on the HTML side. TIA!!

Comment: Add a timestamp field in your model, for example, `db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be sufficient if you add another column to the database model that holds a timestamp. This is automatically filled with a value as soon as the database entry is created. So your requirements should be met.

```
from datetime import datetime

class Files(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
        nullable=False, unique=False, index=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)
    # ...
```

You can use [Flask-Moment](https://flask-moment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to show the timestamp. It uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to display.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much. So for when i'm adding the file to the database using "new_file = Files(name=f.filename, data=f.read())", what would I make the "created_at" parameter equal to when posting this file to the db?

Comment: You do not have to do anything. The date is automatically set by the default parameter you specified in the column definition.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) for documentation of the default parameter. If you don't enter anything, the default value is set. However, you can also pass a different date if necessary.

Comment: Hi thanks! That does solve my problem, however the time is showing incorrectly? It's 5:27pm when I uploaded it, but it shows 22:27 in military time, which doesn't add up...

Comment: UTC time is usually used on a server. This creates a time difference to your time zone, which can be eliminated again when it is displayed. You can also pass `datetime.now` as the default value. Then I think the timestamp should match your timezone.